# I want to make my horizontal table go vertical with responsive

Tags: css

i want to make my horizontal table go vertical in responsive. what i mean is that my table is at the moment horizontal, and i want to make it vertical. i dont care if it is with table attributes or div attributes.
thanks.

i dont know what else to write about my problem.

```css
    body {
      background-color: #596770;
        margin-left: 85px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
     margin-top: 102.5px;
        font-size: 18px; /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
      padding: 0px 52px 0px 52px;
     font-size: 35;
     color:white;
      font-family: montserrat, sans-serif;
    }
 table {
 }
    th {
     width: 423px;
     height: 273px;
    }
    .latest img {
     max-width: 100%;
    
    }
    .About {
     margin: -45px 0px 0px -52px;
    }
    /* Bottom left text */
    .bottom-left {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 8px;
        left: 16px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <h2>Latest News</h2>
  <style>
  table, th {
     border: 1px solid black;
  }
  table, tr {
  border: 0px;
  }
  </style>
  <table class="latest">
    <tr>
 <!--Latest news-->
  <th>
   <a href="">
   <img src="img/NemID_app_to.jpg.png" alt="NemID"><img/>
   </a>
  </th>
       <td width="61px">
    <!--second news-->  
  <th>Pic2</th>
       <td width="61px">
    <!--Third news-->  
  <th>Pic3</th>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: what actually are you looking for?? you mentioned your navbar interferences with grid but there is no navbar in your code???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i try to use bootstrap, it is interference with my own CSS.  it is possible, to only let the Bootstrap CSS to work on a special ammount of my website.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%
}
.tr {
  display: table-row;
}
.td {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .tr {
    display: block;
    float: left;
  }
  .td {
    display: block; 
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">Test 1</div>
    <div class="td">Test 2</div>
    <div class="td">Test 3</div>
    <div class="td">Test 4</div>
    <div class="td">Test 5</div>
    <div class="td">Test 6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">Test 1</div>
    <div class="td">Test 2</div>
    <div class="td">Test 3</div>
    <div class="td">Test 4</div>
    <div class="td">Test 5</div>
    <div class="td">Test 6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use bootstrap and have col tags. When the screen is made smaller the columns will shift down vertically. See an example here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/grid/

Comment: i will check on that.

Comment: The bootstrap is interferrence with my navigation bar

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your example, you don't want an actual table, but some grid to place the news items. I don't know which browsers you want to support, but [CSS Grid layout](https://gridbyexample.com/what/) may be the solution. Then you can define a different grid depening on the screen width.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking for:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
      <![endif]-->

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4a</div>
      <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-4a</div>
      <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4a</div>
      <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4a</div>
      <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-4a</div>
      <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4a</div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4b</div>
      <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-4b</div>
      <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4b</div>
      <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4b</div>
      <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-4b</div>
      <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4b</div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <header>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

resize the window to see effect